# How to use non-aggregate columns used in the SELECT clause without using it in GROUP BY clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server, zoho

I am running this query and I get correct result

```
SELECT
         CONCAT("year", ' - ', TRIM('20' FROM "year") + 1) as 'Years',
         SUM("svalue") as 'Value',
         'Sale' as 'Type',
         "year" as 'Year',
         "code" as 'FACode',
FROM  "FCJOIN" 
WHERE    "code"  IN
    (
    SELECT "fccode"
    FROM  "fcdetails" 
    )
 AND    "month"  between '04'  and  '12'
 AND    "year"  IN ( '2016'  , '2017'  , '2018'  , '2019'  )
GROUP BY "code", "year"
```

what i need is , if I add a new column ***formonth*** it will gives an error Improper usage of GROUP BY clause ? Please ensure that all non-aggregate columns used in the SELECT clause are also used in GROUP BY clause.

that's my modified query is like this

```
SELECT
         CONCAT("year", ' - ', TRIM('20' FROM "year") + 1) as 'Years',
         SUM("svalue") as 'Value',
         'Sale' as 'Type',
         "year" as 'Year',
         "code" as 'FACode',
         **"formonth" as 'Period'**
FROM  "FCJOIN" 
WHERE    "code"  IN
    (
    SELECT "fccode"
    FROM  "fcdetails" 
    )
 AND    "month"  between '04'  and  '12'
 AND    "year"  IN ( '2016'  , '2017'  , '2018'  , '2019'  )
GROUP BY "code", "year"
```

is there any way to make this correct group by or or there any way to rewrite ? I dont want the newly added column in group by clause. i am trying this in zoho reports. Any help ?

Comment: You typically `GROUP BY` the same columns as you `SELECT`, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Comment: Please add sample data to your question and also tell us what you are trying to do.

Comment: What does formonth represents?

Comment: formonth is column from database containing string values

Answer (score 1):

if you want to show the months of each year for which the code was applicable, then you could aggregate their descriptions/strings with string_agg(). For multiple levels of aggregation i.e sum(svalue) group by (code, year) or  group by (year, month description/period) GROUPING SETS could be used.

```
declare @fcdetails table (fccode int)
insert into @fcdetails(fccode) values(1), (2), (3);

declare @fcjoin table
(
    [year] char(4),
    [month] tinyint,
    svalue int,
    code int
) ;

insert into @fcjoin([year], [month], svalue, code)
values
('2016', 5, 10, 1), ('2016', 6, 10, 1), ('2016', 7, 10, 1), 
('2017', 5, 4, 2), ('2017', 6, 4, 2), 
('2018', 7, 10, 3);

declare @othertable table
(
[themonth] tinyint,
period varchar(20)

);

insert into @othertable([themonth], period)
select distinct [month], {fn MONTHNAME(datefromparts('2020', [month], 1))}
from @fcjoin;


SELECT 
         CONCAT("year", ' - ', TRIM('20' FROM "year") + 1),
         SUM("svalue") as 'Value',
         'Sale' as 'Type',
         "year" as 'Year',
         "code" as 'FACode',
         string_agg(o.period, ',') as forperiod

FROM  @FCJOIN as f
join @othertable as o on f.month = o.themonth --careful with joins & aggregations
WHERE    "code"  IN
    (
    SELECT "fccode"
    FROM  @fcdetails
    )
 AND    "month"  between '04'  and  '12'
 AND    "year"  IN ( '2016'  , '2017'  , '2018'  , '2019'  )
GROUP BY "code", "year"; 

SELECT 
         CONCAT("year", ' - ', TRIM('20' FROM "year") + 1),
         SUM("svalue") as 'Value',
         'Sale' as 'Type',
         "year" as 'Year',
         "code" as 'FACode',
         (select string_agg(o.period, ',') 
         from @othertable as o
         where o.themonth in
         (select b.month from @FCJOIN as b where b.year = f.year and b.code = f.code) 

         ) as forperiod

FROM  @FCJOIN as f
WHERE    "code"  IN
    (
    SELECT "fccode"
    FROM  @fcdetails
    )
 AND    "month"  between '04'  and  '12'
 AND    "year"  IN ( '2016'  , '2017'  , '2018'  , '2019'  )
GROUP BY "code", "year"; 

SELECT 
         CONCAT("year", ' - ', TRIM('20' FROM "year") + 1),
         SUM("svalue") as 'Value',
         'Sale' as 'Type',
         "year" as 'Year',
         "code" as 'FACode',
         o.period as forperiod

FROM  @FCJOIN as f
join @othertable as o on f.month = o.themonth --careful with joins & aggregations
WHERE    "code"  IN
    (
    SELECT "fccode"
    FROM  @fcdetails
    )
 AND    "month"  between '04'  and  '12'
 AND    "year"  IN ( '2016'  , '2017'  , '2018'  , '2019'  )
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS(("code", "year"),("year", o.period) /*,(code, o.period)*/);
```